# "If" statement does not execute properly c++

Tags: c++, if-statement, codeblocks

I am having a small issue regarding the `if` statement in c++.
Here is a snippet of the code:

```
string answer;
cin >> answer;

if (answer == "stay in bed")
{
   cout << "You lay there, motionless. Silent.";
}
else if (answer == "go to the bathroom")
{
   cout << "You get up and walk across the hall to the bathroom.";
}
else if (answer == "go downstairs")
{
   cout << "You get up and walk down the stairs to the kitchen.";
}
else
{
   cout << "That is not a valid answer...";
}
```

When I input any value, I get the output from the `else` statement. As in, `"That is not a valid answer..."`

Any advice? Also I'm doing all this in `Code::Blocks`.

Comment: No I Did'nt Pay Attention To The Question.But I Use Them For Chars.Just Got Them Confused.My Bad!!@DavidSaxon

Comment: Okay, I'll do that. Haha like I said im new at this so I know slightly less than nothing... But thank you so much!

Comment: you would want to add "cout<<answer;" to see what was registered. (I'm thinking the whitespace is the culprit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a `getline()` function because `std::cin` only does not accept with spaces but 
with a getline it accepts until a newline appears

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
string answer;
getline(cin, answer);

if (answer == "stay in bed")
{
    cout << "You lay there, motionless. Silent.";
}
else if (answer == "go to the bathroom")
{
    cout << "You get up and walk across the hall to the bathroom.";
}
else if (answer == "go downstairs")
{
    cout << "You get up and walk down the stairs to the kitchen.";
}
else
{
    cout << "That is not a valid answer...";
}
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Two things: Comparison of strings is case dependent; Secondly the input operator `>>` separates on whitespace, so you can't use it to input multiple words and which leads to the problem you're having.

You might want to use e.g. [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) instead, to read a whole line in one go.

Comment: Aaaa okay I see. Is there any way I can have multiple words as an option for an answer? Thank you so much for the answer by the way!

Comment: @Username_000 Yes, by using the `std::getline` function instead as I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

To give you an idea of what you want to do.  Its always a safer bet to setup your conditional statements in that format.  Can save you from a nasty error of using the = instead of ==.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string answer;
    std::getline(std::cin,answer);

    if ("stay in bed" == answer) {
        std::cout << "You lay there, motionless. Silent.";
    }
    else if ("go to the bathroom" == answer) {
        std::cout << "You get up and walk across the hall to the bathroom.";
    }
    else if ("go downstairs" == answer) {
        std::cout << "You get up and walk down the stairs to the kitchen.";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "That is not a valid answer...";
    }

    std::cout << '\n';
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question! It is definitely a good tip though.

Answer (score -1):

Use gets() it will work

```
string answer;

gets(answer);
```

this will capture the white spaces untill you press enter

Comment: i guess u also have to use 
#include<string.h>

Comment: `gets` works for C-style strings, is prone to buffer overflows, and is deprecated.